# What is causing the error “expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘.’ token”?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm currently working to make an indexer for the students score, but, since I am new in C, I dont get the grasp of reading errors. Here's the error I have:

1. c:11:27: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘.’ token
   11 | double average(float input.score, int input.many){
2. c:34:13: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   34 |  for(i=0; i < nas->many; i++){
3. c:48:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘average’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   48 |  average(sum, nas->many);
4. The while loop won't work properly

This is the code I work on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

typedef struct{
    float score, avg, sum, *many;
    char name[100][100];
} input;    
    
double average(float input.score, int input.many){
    float sum=0, average, a;
    int i;
        
    for(i=0; i<input.many;i++){
        sum += input[i].score;
    }
    a = sum/input.many;
    average=a;
    
    return average;
}

int main(){
        
    input nas[MAX];
    
    float sum;
    int choose, i, aa;
    
    printf("How many students do you want to input?\n");
    scanf(" %d",&nas->many);
    
    for(i=0; i < nas->many; i++){
        input nas[i];
    
        printf("\nName of Student-%d\t\t: ",i+1);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", nas[i].name);
        printf("The score of Student-%d\t\t: ",i+1);
        scanf(" %f", &nas[i].score);
    
        while(nas[i].score > 100 && nas[i].score < 0){
            printf("Invalid! Please re-input the score\t\t: ");
            scanf(" %f",&nas[i].score);
        }
        average(sum, nas->many);
    }
    
    printf("1--> Average of the scores");
    scanf("%d", &choose);   
    
    if(choose == 1){
        printf("The average of %d students is %f", nas->many, average());
    }
    ...
    else{ return 0;}
```

Can anybody help me to understand it? Thank you very much

Comment: 1. You cannot use `.` in function argument declarations. 2. `i<input.many` is comparing `int` and `float*`. This looks weird. You may have to use a variable to store the length of the array. 3. The definition of `average` is invalid due to 1. 4. Loops won't work because your code won't compile.

Comment: @SZise Hello, I lost a little time editing your code and try to compreend it, you has a lot of erros, and I already make it! You can check bellow

Comment: @MikeCAT so, for number 2 I need to declare another variable to store the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have some variables on struct thats do not make any sens, and you have some errors by send the parameters to the function and calling the function! You want the average of N students so you only can call the function after the insertion of score!

Other thing is why you need to save on every student, the sum of scores of all students, as the average of all students! And you are declaring the function always on `for` so when you insert for 1 student when loops back you lost your data because you declares it again!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX 100

typedef struct{
    float score;
    char name[100];
} input;    
    
float average(input nas[], int many){
    float sum=0, a;
    int i;
        
    for(i=0; i< many;i++){
        sum += nas[i].score;
    }
    a = sum / many;
    
    return a;
}

int main(){
        
    input nas[MAX];
    
    float sum;
    int choose, i, many;
    
    printf("How many students do you want to input: ");
    scanf(" %d", &many);
    
    for(i=0; i < many; i++){
    
        printf("\nName of Student (%d): ",i+1);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", nas[i].name);
        printf("The score of Student (%d): ",i+1);
        scanf("%f", &nas[i].score);
    
        while(nas[i].score > 100 && nas[i].score < 0){
            printf("Invalid! Please re-input the score: ");
            scanf("%f", &nas[i].score);
        }
    }    

    sum = average(nas, many);
    
    printf("\n1--> Average of the scores: ");
    scanf("%d", &choose);   
    
    if(choose == 1){
        for(int j=0; j < many; j++){
            printf("\nName of Student: %s | Score: %f", nas[j].name, nas[j].score);

        }
        printf("\n\nThe average of %d students is %f\n", many, sum);
    }
    else{ 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is dumb questions, why nas from main used in float function, not from the struct directly? and why input.many is reduced to many, isn't it will lose it's value from the struct, too?

Comment: @SZise why you need to to save on your structure the quantity of many? Like student 1 will have the nas.many student 2 will have nas.many, and why you need to save the quantity of students in every student? I do not understand the question "why nas from main used in float function, not from the struct directly?"

Answer (score 2):

Because you mustn’t use `.` inside a C identifier. It’s not valid. You could for instance replace it with `_`.

[The only valid characters in a C identifier are letters, digits and underscore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier) (ignoring Unicode).

Comment: This is new and it seem never mentioned before. So, thank you very much!

Comment: @SZise I guess you mean new *for you*? Because the rule itself isn’t new: it has existed since the creation of the C language, almost 50 years.

Comment: yeah this is new to me and I even don't fully understand how a thing or two works

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", nas[i].name);
```

are you expecting the user entered field `name` to be followed by a '\n' then a `s`?

Probably not.

Also, this statement does not remove the '\n' from `stdin`.

Therefore, IF anything, that `s` should be replaced with a space (so any trailing 'white space' is consumed.  However, that is 'always' a bad idea.)
Strongly suggest using:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", nas[i].name);  // note: no trailing `s`
```

note the next call to `scanf()` with a `%f` specifier will consume any leading 'white space'.

regarding:

```
scanf(" %d",&nas->many);
```

This may result in the first element in the array `nas[]` field `many` being set, but a much better method is:

```
scanf(" %d",&nas[0]->many);
```

regarding: right after the `for()` statement:

```
input nas[i];
```

This is declaring/re-declaring a new array with however many elements the `i` variable indicates.  Probably not what you want to do.

regarding:

```
char name[100][100];
```

This is declaring a 2 dimensional array of 100 entries, with each entry being 100 characters.  However, when ever the posted code references this 2d array, all that is given is `name`.  The result will be all names will overlay each other in the first [0] entry

regarding:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", nas[i].name);
```

besides the previously mentioned problem with the format string, and with using `name` without any indexing, the specifier: `%[\n]` does not limit the length of a name.  Suggest:

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", nas[i].name[i]);
```

There are LOTS of other problems in the posted code besides those mentioned above.

Comment: Okay, that something new for the string. I wrote '&nas->many' because I thought that will set memories for every input, so later on will be easily accessed for another purposes. `.name[i]` what's this and the logic behind it?. Any way, thank you for helping me!

Comment: regarding: *.name[i] what's this and the logic behind it?*  the field  `name[][]`  is a 2 dimensional array of 100 rows with 100 characters  per row  so `.name[i]` is selecting the `ith` row.  The result is that each new 'name' string is in a different row